# Unable to open log for Persistent Connection, i.e. push log on iPhone

Tags: ios, debugging, logging, apple-push-notifications, xcode-organizer

I have tried to enable push notification logging on my iPhone according to these instructions: [Apple Technical Note 2265](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html).

I have managed to install the PersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig file without any problems. When looking in the console window for my device, I get the following warning:

```
<Warning>: Unable to open logging file '/var/mobile/Library/Logs/PersistentConnection/com.apple.syncdefaultsd-syncdefaultsd-APSClient.log'
```

What does this really mean? It seems to me like that it is failing to create the logging file on my computer :(

I have created the path on my computer.

Has anyone encountered the same problem? Is it possible to set the path where the log shall be saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, the logging via the Organizer does not seems to be working. According to the technical note, console logging is not available in iOS 6.x. However I could read the log using iTunes.

You must connect your device and synchronize it. After this the crash log should be found here (on Mac OS X):

```
~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/<DEVICE_NAME>/PersistentConnection/
```

I hope this helps someone.

Comment: How do you do that with iTunes? Where in iTunes UI is it?

Comment: @StenPetrov

You start iTunes and synchronize it with your device. Updated the answer with this information as well.

Comment: I found the folder, it was on the mac drive, not on the phone. There isn't a 'PersistentConnection' folder though

Comment: Updated the answer to clarify that the log file is found on the computer, not the device.

@StenPetrov I guess that it could be in other places, depending on the version of iTunes.